# Jenkins - Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure in linux environment

Tags: angularjs, linux, jenkins, angular-cli

Configured Angular CLI project with Jenkins, **ng build --env=prod** command working fine in **Jenkins - windows** environment, but in **Jenkins - Unix** it is throwing below error. Tried below options but no luck

```
1. set +e

2 #!/bin/bash

[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/tomcat8/temp/hudson2478899598123360122.sh
+ set +e
+ ng build --env=prod --bh=./
```

[image]

**Error**

```
 63% building modules 772/861 modules 89 active ...er-pipe/dist/src/ng2-filter.module.jsKilled
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: it's saying "Killed" there. any idea what might be killing it?

Comment: Not sure @burnettk, may I know how to find it?

Comment: you might check syslog or similar on the machine where it's running? wild guessing, but maybe the machine ran out of memory and the OOMKiller took it out. i doubt that a build that someone manually aborted would say "Killed" but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Sure, will check and let you know.! Thanks.

Comment: @burnettk, thanks it was because of system memory. Please post it as an answer will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying "Killed" in the log there. Check syslog or similar on the machine where it's running. Maybe the machine ran out of memory and the OOMKiller took it out.

Comment: Thanks, after increasing the memory, it showed proper error.!